# Google Map Autocomplete(Address) set the default search text and show the prediction dropdown on page load

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have tried to set the value on the Autocomplete control and set the focus from java script. The value is set to the field but the list of predictions are not displayed when page is loaded.How can I also show the prediction list with the initial search string set on the field when page is loaded.Please see the below the code.

Please note as soon as user click on the control(Manually) the dropdown is displayed.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="address" style="width: 500px;"></input>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            });
            //$("#address").val('George Street');
            $("#address").focus();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nor sure why this is tagged [google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2), that version of the API has been deprecated, turned off and replaced with a wrapper for v3.  Your code looks like it is using v3.

Comment: Thank you I have changed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this. I have hooked the code to set the value and set the focus on the control in the DOM Event 'load' as below

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
            $("#address").val("George Street");
            $("#address").focus();
        });
```

Comment: After several pages of searching, I finally came across the answer I was looking for. Thanks!